# New Seagate External Hard Disk not recognised

Tags: mount, hard-disk, fdisk

When I connected the **Seagate** Hard Drive in windows it does not recognize the hard disk,but shows up in safely removed options.In Ubuntu 14.04,it does not recognise the hard disk.

Here is the ***lsusb*** message where the disk info is shown:

```
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0bc2:ab26 Seagate RSS LLC 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 8087:07dc Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 1bcf:2b90 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Here is the *fdisk -l* info :

```
WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sda'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.


 Disk /dev/sda: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
 255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders, total 1953525168 sectors
 Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
 Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
 I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
 Disk identifier: 0xcb4662fa

 Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
 /dev/sda1               1  1953525167   976762583+  ee  GPT
 Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.
```

Here is the *dmesg* output :

```
[ 2275.753900] usb 2-1: new SuperSpeed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[ 2275.771624] usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0bc2, idProduct=ab26
[ 2275.771638] usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 2275.771646] usb 2-1: Product: BUP Slim RD
[ 2275.771652] usb 2-1: Manufacturer: Seagate
[ 2275.771657] usb 2-1: SerialNumber: NA97LG8X
[ 2275.775221] scsi host3: uas
[ 2275.776116] scsi 3:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Seagate  BUP Slim RD      0108 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[ 2275.777453] sd 3:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[ 2323.918346] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Spinning up disk...
[ 2344.978027] ...not responding...
[ 2517.874976] sd 3:0:0:0: tag#0 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 1 inflight: CMD IN 
[ 2517.874988] sd 3:0:0:0: tag#0 CDB: Read capacity(16) 9e 10 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 20 00 00
[ 2517.875072] scsi host3: uas_eh_bus_reset_handler start
[ 2517.987245] usb 2-1: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[ 2518.005080] scsi host3: uas_eh_bus_reset_handler success
[ 2528.003082] sd 3:0:0:0: tag#0 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 1 inflight: CMD 
[ 2528.003099] sd 3:0:0:0: tag#0 CDB: Test Unit Ready 00 00 00 00 00 00
[ 2528.003109] scsi host3: uas_eh_bus_reset_handler start
[ 2528.115502] usb 2-1: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[ 2528.135546] scsi host3: uas_eh_bus_reset_handler success
[ 2528.135563] sd 3:0:0:0: Device offlined - not ready after error recovery
[ 2528.135630] sd 3:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
[ 2528.135654] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Read Capacity(16) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[ 2528.135661] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Sense not available.
[ 2528.135670] sd 3:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
[ 2528.135679] sd 3:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
[ 2528.135688] sd 3:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
[ 2528.135698] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[ 2528.135704] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Sense not available.
[ 2528.135712] sd 3:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
[ 2528.135721] sd 3:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
[ 2528.135732] sd 3:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
[ 2528.135740] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[ 2528.135748] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 00 00 00 00
[ 2528.135756] sd 3:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
[ 2528.135763] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Asking for cache data failed
[ 2528.135769] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[ 2528.135777] sd 3:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
[ 2528.135785] sd 3:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
[ 2528.135793] sd 3:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
[ 2528.136447] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
```

Comment: Interesting. Ideas: (1) I've never seen "Spinning up disk..." in dmesg. Can you hear the disk spinning up? (2) If the USB-SATA bridge is faulty: Can you open Seagate enclosure, and connect the disk directly with SATA, or put it in a different enclosure that's known to be working? (3) As next step I'd probably try to use `sg3-utils`, `smartctl` etc. to see what the disk thinks its doing.

Comment: I am also having the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here with same model: 0bc2:ab26
Found: https://github.com/gmircea/Linux/wiki/Install-Guide-Debian

```
$ echo options usb-storage quirks=0bc2:ab26:u | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist_uas_0bc2.conf
$ sudo update-initramfs -u
```

Not tried yet.